# ANTLR tree has no child nodes?

Tags: java, parsing, grammar, antlr4

So, I have a very simple ANTLR4 grammar:

```
grammar TestGrammar;

@header {
    package com.xxxxxx;
}

start_rule: (Function | IDENTIFIER)* EOF;

Function
    :
    IDENTIFIER Parameter
    ;


Parameter
    : '(' (IDENTIFIER) ')'
    ;

IDENTIFIER
    :
    ('A'..'Z' | 'a'..'z')*
    ;

WS
    :   [ \t]+
        -> skip
    ;

OTHER : . -> skip ; //make it a fuzzy parser
```

This is of course a contrived example, but exhibits the problem I have. When I feed it some example input like:

```
foo bar(x) baz
```

I expect to get a tree with foo and baz of course. But also I would expect to see a bar node with two subnodes, one for the identifier name of the function, and then one for the parameter name.

However, what I actually end up seeing is just a flat list of tokens with seemingly no way to recurse down further in the Function token. Like this:

[image: tree]

I'm walking this tree by overriding the BaseListener that is generated. When watching the visitEveryRule function in it, I see a node for each top level rule, but no children node for Parameter is encountered.

How can I accomplish separately retrieving the parameter identifier token(name) and the function identifier token?

Comment: Change `Function` to `function`.

Comment: @saka1029 well that seems to work... How do I find out about these various capitalization conventions in ANTLR?

Comment: See [Rule Elements](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/parser-rules.md#rule-elements). "Tokens always begin with a capital letter." and "Parser rule names always begin with a lowercase letter."